# form submit doesn't reach controller method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using form.submit() to download a file from an ASP.NET MVC (3) site.
Most of the times it's working just fine, but in some use cases (always the same ones) it fails to even reach the controller.

Here is the basic javascript code:

```
var url = "/Correspondence/LoadAttachment/";
        var form = $('<form id="RemoveMe" action="' + url + '" method="post" style="display: none;"></form>');
        var referenceId = Case.CurrentCase.CaseReferenceId.ReferenceId;
        var username = Case.CurrentCase.CustomerData.CorrespondenceData.Username;
        var caseId = Case.CurrentCase.Id;
        var token = new Date().getTime();
        var fileDownloadCheckTimer;

        form.append('<input name="mailId"       value="' + mid + '" />');
        form.append('<input name="fileName"     value="' + fileName + '" />');
        form.append('<input name="username"     value="' + username + '" />');
        form.append('<input name="caseId"     value="' + caseId + '" />');
        form.append('<input type="hidden"     name="downloadToken" value="' + token + '" />');


        form.submit();
```

And here is the basic controller code:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult LoadAttachment()
        {
            try
            {
                uint mailId;
                UInt32.TryParse(Request.Form["mailId"], out mailId);
...

                return new FileContentResult(attachment.BinaryContent, attachment.ContentType)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = attachment.Filename
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogErrorMessage(() => ex.ToString());
                return Json("");
            }
        }
```

Now even if I put the same values in the form that works fine for one use case in the failed use case, it still fails. So the problem must be somewhere else. But I can't figure out where for the life of me...

B.T.W , the problem is reproduced in Chrome and FireFox browsers

Answer (score 0):

If this is being done as a POST you need to decorate the method with the 
HttpPost attribute like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadAttachment()
{
...
}
```

If you find that you aren't getting your values within the Request.Form then you can always try using the FormCollection as an argument in your method and then use string indexes to retrieve values of fields.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadAttachment(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    string name = formCollection["Name"];
}
```

**Brain Food**

[Some best Practices for MVC](https://curah.microsoft.com/198908/aspnet-mvc-dos-and-donts-best-practices)

[Securing your MVC4 App Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but... 1. HttpPost doesn't help. 2. I don't have problems reading the values from the request form. the request doesn't reach the controller at all, as I mentioned only for specific cases

Comment: @omerschleifer Can I ask why you aren't using the @Html.BeginForm(){} helper to build your form? Do you want me to link to some examples?

Comment: The form is generated on the client side dynamically, I can't create it in advance at the server side using razor

Comment: In that case I don't feel this is am issue of MVC routing and the submit not posting I think its that you haven't built the form correctly in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you edit answer withe the page source on load please where the form is here

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your request. As for the form not being built correctly,  I don't think that's the issue, as it sometimes does work, I've copied values that work, and in the not working scenario sent them in the form it still doesn't work. So it has to be somewhere else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72647/discussion-between-glitch100-and-omer-schleifer).

Comment: @Glitch100 As far as I remember you don't need to decorate controller action with `HttPostAttribute` in order to achive post functionality.